# Arbitrary virtual screens

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I would like to redefine the screen space my monitors provide. Currently, I have two monitors on my computer with a screen size of 1680x1080 each. I would like to re-define this space to be 3 monitors with the same total size, e.g. one with 1680x1080 and two with 840x1080.
Important for me: For Windows 7, these should be "real" monitors, so I get native handling.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: To get "native handling", you'll need OS and Graphics driver support. AFAIK, this will be impossible, if not, very difficult to pull off. This is an odd request. What is your end result? Do you need programs to run in each screen? Do you need to test screen coordinates?

Comment: I just want to use my screen space more efficient. On the other hand, I always maximize my windows out of habit... So, defining virtual screens would solve both problems. Basically, what I want is what all those programs achieve that lets you define a grid for your desktop the windows maximize in. However, I have found no program so far that feels natural.

Comment: 8 years later with 5120x1440 monitors this makes even more sense... Sadly there seem to be no such utility.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to use my screen space more efficient. On the other hand,
>   I always maximize my windows out of habit... So, defining virtual
>   screens would solve both problems. Basically, what I want is what all
>   those programs achieve that lets you define a grid for your desktop
>   the windows maximize in. However, I have found no program so far that
>   feels natural.

There are two options you should try.

The first is a screen grid program, like [Acer Gridvista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14334/snap-app-windows-to-pre-defined-screen-sections-with-acer-gridvista/). I have not personally tried the program myself.  There are others out there that are similar.

The second option is Display Fusion.  Window's AeroSnap only functions on the far left and far right of your multimonitor's display. To say have a window occupy the inner half of a two monitor setup, you have to use the keyboard (  <kbd>WIN</kbd> +   <kbd>Right</kbd> OR   <kbd>Left</kbd>).  Display Fusion allows you to snap windows to the inner halves of your setup with the mouse also.

Comment: AeroSnap works to all screens.  I have three monitors and I just tested it with an Outlook mail message - if I start with it as a window in the middle, I can use [WIN]+[Left] multiple times and each press moves it either one half screen to the left or "restores" it's original dimensions on the new screen.

Comment: Yeah, I know it works on all screens. I noted above that it only works for the keyboard and not the mouse.  Display Fusion creates a "snapping" zone for mouse dragged windows in the inner halves of your configuration.